# Is there a list of notifications which are posted by the default notification center?

Tags: ios

I tried to find one, but couldn't. Would like to know what kind of notifications are posted around in iPhone OS, by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and it wouldn't be meaningful to create such a list.

You can always try:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(watch:) name:nil object:nil];
```

The results are interesting.

Comment: why don't you think that would be meaningful?  that is dynamic discovery -- or am I missing something?  (BTW - i was just about to post the same question.)

Comment: Because notifications are entirely dynamic; any application can create its own custom notfications.  So all you could expect would be a list of what notifications have been observed in the past without any description of them - which is exactly what you can generate with the line of code I gave above.